# JPA Mapping enums to different String

Tags: string, jpa, mapping

In my database are fixed String codes (e.g. "200") which I would like to map to enum constants and I want more understandable names for these constants (like "STATUS_CODE_OK"). So I would like to map enums constants to different String in database.

I think it is not possible to use `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` because it use `Enum.name()` which return enum constant exactly as declared and it is final (so I can't override it).

Is there some way to map it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enjoy best practise here:

Your entity

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Column
    protected String status;

    public Status getStatus() {
        return Status.fromId(status);
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status == null ? null : status.getId();
    }
}
```

Code of Status enum

```
public enum Status {
    OK("200"), NOT_OK("500");

    protected String id;

    Status(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static Status fromId(String id){
        if (id == null) return null;
        else if (OK.id.equals(id)) return OK;
        else if (NOT_OK.id.equals(id)) return NOT_OK;
        else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't parse Status from id : " + id);
    }

}
```

As you can see, you operate with enums in your code and store String values in database.

Comment: I found two solutions: 
1.) use EclipseLink `@Convert` annotation 
or 
2.) use entity listeners and methods with annotations `@PrePersist` and `@PostLoad`. 


But the first solution is dependent on JPA implementation and the second one requires duplicate fields in an entity. This looks much better. Thanks